# NoClassDefFoundError when trying to load a dll in servlet with tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, dll, noclassdeffounderror

I am trying to build a simple java servlet that runs in tomcat server on my machine.

My servlet code is :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class javaservlet
 */
@WebServlet(description = "java servlet", urlPatterns = { "/javaservlet" })
public class javaservlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public javaservlet() {
        super();

        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        calldll callingdll = new calldll();
        ServletContext context = getServletConfig().getServletContext();  
        String path = context.getContextPath(); 
        writer.println(path);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

and it works fine (not of the `calldll callingdll = new calldll();` part i will explain below what error i get there)

I also have a second class that loads the dll file called "calldll.dll" (did all the work with javac , javah and stuff and it works )  my dll is placed in `C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.37\wtpwebapps\myServlet\WEB-INF\lib` and i have pointed build path of native there and  my class code is

```
public class calldll {

    private native void print();

public static void main (String[] args){
    new calldll().print();
}

static {
System.loadLibrary("calldll");  
}

}
```

My c file where i made the dll from is a really simple

```
#include<jni.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<windows.h>
#include "calldll.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_calldll_print(JNIEnv*env,jobject obj)
{
printf("It Works!");
return;
}
```

when i run the javaservlet where i call the call dll class that loads the dll i get this :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class calldll
    javaservlet.doGet(javaservlet.java:33)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

The weird thing is that when i run the java class alone the message "It works" comes up so the class loads the dll successfully. But when when i create an instance of the class in the servlet it doesnt it from the servlet is doesn't that is my problem....

i added to the calldll class

catch(UnsatisfiedLinkError e)
 {
     System.err.println("Native code library failed to load.\n" + e);
 }

to see if it is a problem with static and i get the following error when i run the servlet

```
Native code library failed to load.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no calldll in java.library.path
```

but my calldll class if i execute it alone it still works... so what is happening in the servlet that i do wrong :s

Comment: Add the servlet.jar to your classpath. hope it works. If you are using eclipse you can add as external lib try.

Comment: thanks for the replay can you be more specific about what i have to do ?

Comment: I believe you're getting error with `System.loadLibrary("calldll");`. Catch the exceptions thrown by the `loadLibrary` method. This will help in finding the exact cause of the error.

Comment: i did add what you proposed and i edited my answer please check :)

Comment: Have you checked java.library.path to make sure calldll is definitely there?

Comment: yea my dll is now at my program in eclipse in WEBINF/libs and i pointed java build path there for native but still the same error :(

Comment: also checkeb about java build path with System.getProperties().getProperty("java.library.path") and points out to the correct place i got the dll

Answer (score 0):

If your webapp is hosted in tomcat app server copy the dll to bin folder, then in your servlet use :

```
System.load(System.getProperty("catalina.base")+"/bin/yourdll.dll");
```